# SQL I got multiple rows altough I have only one product

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 product options but I got 4 rows of it why ? It display me the product options 2x in my array

[Link to sql online code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/49c41/2)

Code:

```
SELECT 
      p.id,
      p.shop_id,
      p.provider_id,
      p.name,
      p.status,
      
      json_agg(json_build_object(
        'id', pt.id,
        'tag', pt.tag
      )) AS tags,
      
      json_agg(json_build_object(
        'id', po.id,
        'name', po.name
      )) AS product_options
      
      FROM product p
      
      LEFT JOIN product_options po
      ON po.p_id = p.id
      
      LEFT JOIN product_tags pt
      ON pt.p_id = p.id
      
      WHERE p.id = 1
      
      GROUP BY
      p.id
```

You can see when you click the link there are 4 objects in product options in the array but I only have two records in product options why I get 4 ?

Comment: `GROUP BY p.id` ? Remove `po.id` from the  `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @TheImpaler Hello thanks this resolved the issue but I have another problem, I created a new table named product tags there are 2 records  but in my array I have 4 objects why?

Comment: maybe you can create new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `po.id` from group by. It will be like this:

```
SELECT 
      p.id,
      p.shop_id,
      p.provider_id,
      p.name,
      p.status,
      
      json_agg(json_build_object(
        'id', po.id,
        'name', po.name
      )) AS product_options
      
      FROM product p
      
      LEFT JOIN product_options po
      ON po.p_id = p.id
      
      WHERE p.id = 1
      
      GROUP BY
      p.id
```

Here is the sample result:
[image]

Here is the [sample fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b9e1ac/3)

For follow-up question, that is because of the joins in your SQL query. When you join the product_options and product_tags tables separately, it can lead to a Cartesian product, causing each product to be duplicated for each matching row in the product_options and product_tags tables. To avoid that, you can use subqueries to perform the aggregation of product_options and product_tags separately for each product, and then joining them with the main product table.

Here is the sample code:

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.shop_id,
    p.provider_id,
    p.name,
    p.status,
    
    (
        SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
            'id', pt.id,
            'tag', pt.tag
        ))
        FROM product_tags pt
        WHERE pt.p_id = p.id
    ) AS tags,
    
    (
        SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
            'id', po.id,
            'name', po.name
        ))
        FROM product_options po
        WHERE po.p_id = p.id
    ) AS product_options
    
FROM product p
WHERE p.id = 1;
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Here is the [sample fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/49c41/11)

Comment: hi thank you I have edited my posts I created product tags table and now I get in my product options 2x the same data I got 4 objects in my product option although I only have 2 records in product options